# Dealing with server overload bursts?

Tags: apache-2.2, vps

On my website, VPS server with 2 GB RAM, I host a repository which users can download some small package (about 2 MB) to their machines.

Problem is, over time, this repo got highly popular - tens of thousands of users if not hundreds of thousands, and now every time I update the package the server gets severely overloaded until cache starts kicking into action.
But this may take hours (last time - a couple of days) until load start to subside again.

I tried increasing the RAM to 4 GB but there was no noticeable improvement. buying more than that is simply too costly.

Is there any way I could tackle these updates without getting swamped?

**Edit:** I should've mentioned it from the start, I've already tried CloudFlare, however, using CF takes away my control over the caching time of zip files, thus my updates never got in time to my clients.

I'm mostly looking for a way to make connections get queued without overloading the server (if that's even possible)...

Comment: Have you tried switching to Nginx?

Comment: When I was using Cloudflare, I used to check the http response headers and it was saying that the server was Nginx. So I assume it may alleviate the problem but won't solve it. Thank you

Comment: Cloudflare puts Nginx-based servers in front of yours, that doesn't change anything about your server and its (in)ability to serve that much concurrent requests. You should switch to Nginx on your server as well as it handles concurrent requests much better (it's event-based vs thread-based, so it can serve more requests using only one thread per CPU).

Comment: Or switch to apache 2.4 with mpm_event.  Nearly the same performance as nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Two fairly easy-to-implement solutions:

1. Put Cloudflare in front of your server. This will distribute requests for that file to Cloudflare's CDN and alleviate some of your server load.
2. Serve the file directly from Amazon S3 (or something like that). S3 will easily push as much data to your users as they could possibly generate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into the Amazon solution...

Answer (score 2):

2 MB of static content should stay in file system cache if requested that frequently.

Use a content delivery network to scale out to many global nodes and take the load off your web server.

You could tune httpd MPM and possibly pick a different one. worker is a threaded option. Try an initial thread limit a bit higher than the peak request rate observed before.